# why abs() function in dart return negative number when not wrapped in parenthesis?

Tags: dart

The `abs()` function has no effect When calling on negative number literal.

`var y = -123.11.abs(); // prints -123.11`

but other functions, for example `floor()` works fine

`var y = -123.11.floor(); // prints -123`

If I wrap the negative number literal in parenthesis it works fine

`var y = (-123.11).abs(); // prints 123.11`

Any help to understand this behaviour is appreciated.

The dart version I use is `Dart VM version: 2.2.1-dev.0.0.flutter-571ea80e11 (Mon Mar 4 19:30:53 2019 +0000) on "windows_x64"`

**Update:**
Note: the `floor()` does not work correctly when applied on negative number as pointed by @HighPerformanceMark

Comment: I just realised what could be happening here. I think it first applies `abs()` on a number literal without considering the negative sign then negates the whole result. Is that correct?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I think it is relevant and you are right. if I wrap the negative number before applying `floor`, it returns `-124`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to [Operator precedence](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#operators) and [Dart Language Specification](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/spec)`-123.11.abs()` is the same as `-((123.11).abs())`.