# how to convert negative int to positive int in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

for example if i have a list like

```
List list = [-12,3,-24,58,12];
```

i have already tried this ,i did not understand it [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374813/why-abs-function-in-dart-return-negative-number-when-not-wrapped-in-parenthesi\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374813/why-abs-function-in-dart-return-negative-number-when-not-wrapped-in-parenthesi%5C)
i want to convert all parameters to a positive parameters
or if i had only a integer which is negative how to convert it to a positive integer 
**if you need more information please let me know and thanks for the helps**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why abs() function in dart return negative number when not wrapped in parenthesis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55374813/why-abs-function-in-dart-return-negative-number-when-not-wrapped-in-parenthesi)

Comment: `var nonnegatives = [for (var i in list) i.abs()];`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use Abs method for numbers to get absolute value:

```
int number = -5;
print(number.abs()); // prints: 5
```

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#numbers